# Form selecting first radio button on submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an HTML program (excuse the messy code) that was meant to open a Google classroom window and another window (if the user so desired) at a specific time. When submitting the first run `form`, no matter what you select it goes to the first option when you press *Submit*.

```
<form onsubmit="return firstrunFunction2();" class="firstrunfalse" id="Pdls">
  <p>First run:
    <br>To setup, please type the class code for each classroom.
    <br>EX: <i>https://classroom.google.com/u/0/c/<strong> NzA2MDk5NzM5MVpa</strong></i>
    <br>Please <strong>only</strong> put the end code or else the application will fail to run properly.</p>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="pd1" placeholder="Period 1">
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period1" id="period1typemath" value="Math">Math
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period1" id="period1typescience" value="Science">Science
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period1" id="period1typeother" value="Other">Other
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period1" id="period1typecustom" value="Custom">Custom URL:
  <br>
  <input type="textbox" id="period1customurl" placeholder="Custom Url">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="pd2" placeholder="Period 2">
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period2" id="period2typemath" value="Math">Math
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period2" id="period2typescience" value="Science">Science
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period2" id="period2typeother" value="Other">Other
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period2" id="period2typecustom" value="Custom">Custom URL:
  <br>
  <input type="textbox" id="period2customurl" placeholder="Custom Url">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="pd3" placeholder="Period 3">
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period3" id="period3typemath" value="Math">Math
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period3" id="period3typescience" value="Science">Science
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period3" id="period3typeother" value="Other">Other
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period3" id="period3typecustom" value="Custom">Custom URL:
  <br>
  <input type="textbox" id="period3customurl" placeholder="Custom Url">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="pd4" placeholder="Period 4">
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period4" id="period4typemath" value="Math">Math
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period4" id="period4typescience" value="Science">Science
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period4" id="period4typeother" value="Other">Other
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period4" id="period4typecustom" value="Custom">Custom URL:
  <br>
  <input type="textbox" id="period4customurl" placeholder="Custom Url">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="pd5" placeholder="Period 5">
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period5" id="period5typemath" value="Math">Math
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period5" id="period5typescience" value="Science">Science
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period5" id="period5typeother" value="Other">Other
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period5" id="period5typecustom" value="Custom">Custom URL:
  <br>
  <input type="textbox" id="period5customurl" placeholder="Custom Url">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="pd6" placeholder="Period 6">
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period6" id="period6typemath" value="Math">Math
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period6" id="period6typescience" value="Science">Science
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period6" id="period6typeother" value="Other">Other
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period6" id="period6typecustom" value="Custom">Custom URL:
  <br>
  <input type="textbox" id="period6customurl" placeholder="Custom Url">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="pd7" placeholder="Period 7">
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period7" id="period7typemath" value="Math">Math
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period7" id="period7typescience" value="Science">Science
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period7" id="period7typeother" value="Other">Other
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period7" id="period7typecustom" value="Custom">Custom URL:
  <br>
  <input type="textbox" id="period7customurl" placeholder="Custom Url">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="pd8" placeholder="Period 8">
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period8" id="period8typemath" value="Math">Math
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period8" id="period8typescience" value="Science">Science
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period8" id="period8typeother" value="Other">Other
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period8" id="period8typecustom" value="Custom">Custom URL:
  <br>
  <input type="textbox" id="period8customurl" placeholder="Custom Url">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="pd9" placeholder="Period 9">
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period9" id="period9typemath" value="Math">Math
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period9" id="period9typescience" value="Science">Science
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period9" id="period9typeother" value="Other">Other
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period9" id="period9typecustom" value="Custom">Custom URL:
  <br>
  <input type="textbox" id="period9customurl" placeholder="Custom Url">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="pd10" placeholder="Period 10">
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period10" id="period10typemath" value="Math">Algebra
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period10" id="period10typeother" value="Other">Academic Advisor
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="period10" id="period10typecustom" value="Custom">Custom URL:
  <br>
  <input type="textbox" id="period10customurl" placeholder="Custom Url">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="submitFirstrun">
</form>
```

Here is a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/sKRgHPKM).

Comment: Where is the HTML for your form and your submit button?

Comment: Please create a simplified example of the issue, no one will have the time to go through almost 600 lines of code

Comment: `if (document.getElementById('period1typescience').checked = true) {` you might want to focus on lines like this

Comment: @Huangism , This code runs properly. The only problem is when you press the submit button, the selection changes to the upper radio button, which is math.

Comment: @freginold Just updated the post.

Comment: @NathanMetzger your js is wrong, just compare that to your other true/false checks, notice the other ones are using `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: @Huangism Oh yes thank you! That would try and make it checked wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
if (document.getElementById('period1typescience').checked = true) {
    document.cookie = "period1type=science; expires=Mon, 18 Jun 2018 12:00:00 GMT-0400 EDT;";
} else if (document.getElementById('period1typemath').checked = true) {
    document.cookie = "period1type=math; expires=Mon, 18 Jun 2018 12:00:00 GMT-0400 EDT;";
}
....
```

`document.getElementById('period1typescience').checked = true` always returns true.
You want to check for the boolean, you can use

```
document.getElementById('period1typescience').checked == true
```

or

```
document.getElementById('period1typescience').checked === true
```

or even simpler

```
document.getElementById('period1typescience').checked
```

The `.checked` already returns a boolean so you do not need to check to see if it equals true or not. Since that statement is returning true so the first condition always gets set.

This is a problem on pretty much all of your checks for values, not just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. Answering the question "Form selecting first radio button on submit".

```
    // All Browsers
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i of inputs)
        if(i.type.toLowerCase() === 'radio'){
            console.log(i);
            break;
        }

    // New Browsers
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]')[0]);
```